# proguard problems in android studio

Tags: android, proguard

I've develop an app in android studio. It works fine in debug version but when I try to create a release version with proguard, hundreds of warnings appear and I'm not able to get rid of them using -keep option.

My build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ruben.xradar"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 22
        versionName "0.22"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //Esto es para oscurecer y minificar el código
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2') {}

    //para el doble slider
    compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
    //para logearse usando la cuenta de redes sociales
    compile files('src/libs/socialauth-4.12.jar')
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    //google cloud messaging
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    //para hacer el stepper del registro
    compile 'ivb.com.materialstepper:material-stepper:0.0.2'
    //para poder usar material design en versiones pre-lollipop
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    //esto es para los díalogos de cambiar las fotos
    compile 'com.kingfisherphuoc:quick-action-dialog-fragment:1.1'
    //para animar el recyclerview
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.3.0'
    //para usar iconos de fuentes, svg's como iconos y así no tener que            crear carpetas hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi, etc
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.8@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1.original@aar'

    //para hacer imageviews redondos
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
}
```

and finally the proguard wargings messages are:

```
Warning:com.google.api.client.googleapis.testing.TestUtils: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Splitter
Warning:com.google.api.client.googleapis.testing.TestUtils: can't find referenced class com.google.common.collect.Lists
Warning:com.google.api.client.googleapis.testing.TestUtils: can't find referenced class com.google.common.base.Splitter
Warning:com.google.api.client.googleapis.testing.TestUtils: can't find referenced class com.google.common.collect.Lists
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchMoveFinished(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchChangeFinished(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder,boolean)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchRemoveFinished(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchAddFinished(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator$4: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchMoveStarting(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator$4: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchMoveFinished(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator$5: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchChangeStarting(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder,boolean)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator$5: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchChangeFinished(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder,boolean)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator$6: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchChangeStarting(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder,boolean)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator$6: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchChangeFinished(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder,boolean)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator$DefaultAddVpaListener: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchAddStarting(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator$DefaultAddVpaListener: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchAddFinished(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator$DefaultRemoveVpaListener: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchRemoveStarting(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator$DefaultRemoveVpaListener: can't find referenced method 'void dispatchRemoveFinished(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder)' in program class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.BaseItemAnimator
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.ax.FetchRequest
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.AuthRequest
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.OpenIDException
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.ParameterList
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.consumer.VerificationResult
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.discovery.Identifier
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.consumer.VerificationResult
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.AuthSuccess
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.ax.FetchResponse
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerException
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.OpenIDException
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.ParameterList
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.consumer.VerificationResult
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.discovery.Identifier
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.AuthSuccess
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.ax.FetchResponse
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.ax.FetchRequest
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.AuthRequest
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.consumer.VerificationResult
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.discovery.Identifier
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.discovery.DiscoveryInformation
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.AuthRequest
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.ax.FetchRequest
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.OpenIDException
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.ax.FetchResponse
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.AuthSuccess
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.message.ParameterList
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.consumer.VerificationResult
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.discovery.Identifier
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.provider.OpenIdImpl: can't find referenced class org.openid4java.OpenIDException
Warning:org.brickred.socialauth.util.SocialAuthUtil: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
Warning:org.joda.time.DateMidnight: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Duration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Instant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.MutableDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.MutablePeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Period: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractDuration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractPeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Note: android.support.v4.media.IMediaBrowserServiceCallbacksAdapterApi21: can't find dynamically referenced class android.service.media.IMediaBrowserServiceCallbacks
Note: android.support.v4.media.IMediaBrowserServiceCallbacksAdapterApi21: can't find dynamically referenced class android.content.pm.ParceledListSlice
Note: android.support.v4.media.IMediaBrowserServiceCallbacksAdapterApi21$Stub: can't find dynamically referenced class android.service.media.IMediaBrowserServiceCallbacks$Stub
Note: android.support.v4.media.ParceledListSliceAdapterApi21: can't find dynamically referenced class android.content.pm.ParceledListSlice
Note: android.support.v4.text.ICUCompatApi23: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.icu.ICU
Note: android.support.v4.text.ICUCompatIcs: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.icu.ICU
Note: android.support.v7.widget.DrawableUtils: can't find dynamically referenced class android.graphics.Insets
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.Session
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.FacebookSdk
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.Session
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.CallbackManager$Factory
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.login.LoginManager
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.CallbackManager
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.FacebookCallback
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.FacebookSdk
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.login.LoginManager
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.Session
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.login.LoginManager
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.Session$OpenRequest
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.Session
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.FacebookCallback
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.Session
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf$1: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.login.LoginResult
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf$1: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.FacebookException
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf$1: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.AccessToken
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf$2: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
Note: com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzy: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl
Note: com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils: can't find dynamically referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Note: com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils: can't find dynamically referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Note: com.mikepenz.iconics.Iconics calls '(com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.ITypeface)Class.forName(variable).newInstance()'
Note: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone calls '(org.joda.time.tz.Provider)Class.forName(variable).newInstance()'
Note: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone calls '(org.joda.time.tz.NameProvider)Class.forName(variable).newInstance()'
Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'icon' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.kingfisherphuoc.quickactiondialog.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.kingfisherphuoc.quickactiondialog.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.mikepenz.iconics.core.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.mikepenz.iconics.core.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.mikepenz.iconics.utils.StyleContainer { java.lang.String icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.ruben.xradar.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.ruben.xradar.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'ivb.com.materialstepper.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'ivb.com.materialstepper.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog { android.graphics.drawable.Drawable icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.LauncherActivity$ListItem { android.graphics.drawable.Drawable icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.content.pm.ResolveInfo { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard$Key { android.graphics.drawable.Drawable icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$EngineInfo { int icon; }'
Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'title' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.games.internal.player.PlayerColumnNames { java.lang.String title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode$ContactInfo { java.lang.String title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode$UrlBookmark { java.lang.String title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.google.api.client.util.PemReader$Section { java.lang.String title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.kingfisherphuoc.quickactiondialog.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.kingfisherphuoc.quickactiondialog.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.mikepenz.iconics.core.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.mikepenz.iconics.core.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.ruben.xradar.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.ruben.xradar.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'ivb.com.materialstepper.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'ivb.com.materialstepper.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'org.brickred.socialauth.Photo { java.lang.String title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'org.brickred.socialauth.Position { java.lang.String title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.preference.PreferenceActivity$Header { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'actionIntent' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { android.app.PendingIntent actionIntent; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { android.app.PendingIntent actionIntent; }'
Note: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider accesses a field 'environment' dynamically

etc, etc...
```

I don't know why, for example, adding -keep class jp.wasabeef.** {*;} do not dissapear warnings concerning to jp.wasabeef.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: To silence the warnings you can use `-dontwarn`.

Comment: try using this....  -keep class org.brickred.** { *; } -dontwarn org.brickred.**

Comment: @Lucho: I don't want to silence the warnings because then, My app doesn't work fine. I want to keep it out of obfuscation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Shanrais: I don't know why but putting:  "-keep class org.brickred.** {* ; } -dontwarn org.brickred.* " doesn't seem do anything. I'd tried before. I don't know why. Thanks you anyway too.

Comment: please share your proguard-rules.pro; 
check my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need handle each library you imported (in app.gradle) by using proguard-rules.

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
#For JodaTime
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025487/proguard-didnt-compile-with-joda-time-used-in-windows
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.FromString
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.ToString

# support-v4
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978706/obfuscate-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-issue
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }


# support-v7
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }

# support design
#@link http://stackoverflow.com/a/31028536
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

#error : Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
#solution : @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/14463528
-dontnote com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote **ILicensingService

#social auth
-keep class org.brickred.** { ; } 
-dontwarn org.brickred.*

#similarly handle other libraries you added
```

Comment: Thanks @Shanrais. Your answer is clear and has helped me.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use ** { *; } for all support libraries. Why even using proguard then?

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude these externally added library code from obfuscation. So you need to find compatible **-dontwarn**.

> For **joda** add : **-dontwarn org.joda.convert.****

if you are using any **pojo** then you also need to exclude them use:

> **-keepclassmembers class yourpackage.** {< fields>; }**

Comment: Hi @Chintan. dontwarn doesn't exclude, but avoid warning you about an issue. I've put all dontwarn I needed and now the app is created but it doesn't works. I need to exclude the libraries but I don't know the -keep option seems not to work.

Comment: try "-keep" for the classes you needed. and again if you are using POJOs then you must not keep them obfuscated.

Here are some more Data

-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

in order to fix protobuf errors try:
 -keep class com.google.protobuf.** { *; }